# how to create multistep form in cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

I have a table called 'registration' having fields more than 20.I want to create multistep form for the registration process.how to create it in cakephp?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know specifically for CakePHP, but using `session` variables ([PHP Sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)) you can easily do that with pure PHP.

You submit the first part to the second, within the second page, you store the `POST` or `GET` variables into `$_SESSION` variables, which later you access in your next step.

In the subsequent steps, you do the same and access variables from previous form submission and store them into session variables. At the last step, all your data will be in `$_SESSION` + the last form submission variables.